# Density of logarithm with fractional base

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, fractions

Consider the set

$$C=\left\{\log_\frac{a+1}{b+1}\frac{a}{b} : a\ne b\in\mathbb{Z}^+\right\}$$
The set $C$ cannot contain all real numbers in $[1,\infty)$ because it is a countable set. But is it dense in $[1,\infty)$, or in some subinterval of it (of positive length)?

To prove that it is dense, we would need that for any $r\in[1,\infty)$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $a,b$ such that
$$\left|r-\log_\frac{a+1}{b+1}\frac{a}{b} \right| < \epsilon. $$
That is, we need $\log_\frac{a+1}{b+1}\frac{a}{b}$ close to $r$. The form of the expression does not allow us to solve for $a,b$ though.

Comment: have you tried applying the definition? Have you tried finding a counterexample?

Comment: and how do you define $\log_1$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $a\ne b$ (so we don't need $\log_1$). I have included my thoughts.

Comment: The graph of the region $\left|r-\log_\frac{a+1}{b+1}\frac{a}{b} \right| < \epsilon$ with $r = 4$ and $\epsilon = 0.1$ makes it look like there aren't any integer solutions with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$